# Inverse Laplace Transform to Recover CDF

Tags: statistics, laplace-transform

I know we can recover CDF of a variable random $ X $ by using inverse laplace transform. But as far as I know, laplace transform is defined on $ [0,\infty] $. Does it imply that we can only recover CDF of real positive random variable? How about bilateral laplace transform? Does inverse bilateral laplace transform can recover CDF of real variable random $ X $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two-sided Laplace transform, one has to explicitly specify the region of convergence for the inverse transform. If the inverse transform of $F(p)$ is $f$ when $p$ lies in the vertical strip $ROC(f)$, then
$$\mathcal L \!\left[ \int_{-\infty}^t f(\tau) d\tau \right] =
\frac {F(p)} p, \\
p \in ROC(f) \land \operatorname{Re} p > 0.$$
This property can be used to obtain the cdf from the pdf $f$. If you take $p$ in the left half-plane, the answer will differ by $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) d\tau = 1$.

Comment: Can you prove $ \mathcal{L} [ \int_{-\infty}^{t} f(x) dx ] = \frac{F(p)}{p} $ is valid for the two-sided laplace transform? Because when I am trying to prove it, using integration by parts, there is this term $ \lim_{t \to -\infty} - \frac{1}{s} e^{-st} \int_{-\infty}^{t} f(x) dx $ which most likely not to be 0. But this term has to be 0 if the formula for cdf  to be valid. Or is there any connection between the $ ROC(f) $ and this term?

Comment: If the double integral converges absolutely, the domain $t \in \mathbb R, \tau < t$ can be reparametrized as $\tau \in \mathbb R, t > \tau$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt \,e^{-p t} \int_{-\infty}^t d\tau f(\tau)=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\tau f(\tau) \int_\tau^\infty dt \,e^{-p t}.$$

Comment: Hmm I still dont get it. Maybe it is a silly question, is $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) d\tau $ and $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau f(\tau) $ the same? For several times, I have seen this integral, but not sure what it is

Comment: Yes, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) d\tau$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\tau f(\tau)$ are exactly the same. If it's clearer, rewrite the above as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^{-p t} \int_{-\infty}^t f(\tau) d\tau) dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(\tau) \int_\tau^\infty e^{-p t} dt) d\tau$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I get it now, I think that uncommon notation of integral make me confuse. I still have some questions, is there any source for that reparameterization theorem thing? Preferably a book. Does $ ROC $ have something to do with the reparameterization? And what does $ Re \, p $ mean? Is it the same as $ Re(z) $ function in complex theory?

Comment: Note: I understand the reparameterization, when I try to draw the area below the plane of the integration function, it is the same area, but with different order of integration. I remember learnt this in calculus, but I don't remember the requirement that it should converges absolutely

Comment: $\operatorname{Re} p$ is the same as $\operatorname{Re}(p)$, the real part of $p$. If we're assuming that $f$ is a pdf and therefore is non-negative, a sufficient requirement is that either the double integral or one of the iterated integrals exists, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#The_Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem). Your approach of integrating by parts works as well, you need to consider the conditions when the limit at $-\infty$ and the limit at $+\infty$ exist.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your answer. Actually I still have questions regarding ROC, but it would be inappropriate to ask here, because they are outside the question I asked above. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885397/region-of-convergence-of-bilateral-laplace-transform), I would be grateful if you can help me again